# Iterator of a wildcard type variable with upper bound

Tags: java, generics

Hello everybody I try to extend a `HashMap<String,String>` to enforce a "all-lowercase" rule

```
public class HttpQueryMap extends HashMap<String,String>
{    
    ...
    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends String> m)
    {       
        ...
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> iterator = m.entrySet().iterator();
        ...      
    }
    ... 
}
```

I get a compile-time error

```
incompatible types
required: Iterator<Entry<String,String>>
found:    Iterator<Entry<CAP#1,CAP#2>>
where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
CAP#1 extends String from capture of ? extends String
CAP#2 extends String from capture of ? extends String
```

The next work-around does the job but it is really ugly:

```
public class HttpQueryMap extends HashMap<String,String>
{    
    ...
    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends String> m)
    {       
        ...
        Map<String,String> m_str=new HashMap<String,String>();
        m_str.putAll(m);
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> iterator = m_str.entrySet().iterator();
        ...      
    }
    ... 
 }
```

As far as I understand the problem is that the type variable `String` used in the `Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>>` does not extend `String` (itself) used in the declaration of `Map<? extends String, ? extends String> m`

Comment: @arynaq: Irrelevant. It's an override of `putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m)` on a `Map<String, String>`, thus the signature.

Comment: @RyanStewart: It's not irrelevant at all. It's just not the answer to the question, but it is a perfectly valid comment.

Comment: @Keppil: The fact that it's not incorrect doesn't make it relevant to the question. In what way does the fact that String is final apply to this question?

Comment: Have you considered composition here instead of inheritance?  Create a class that implements `Map` for String,String and wraps a `Map<String,String>`, delegating calls to the underlying `Map` and performing conversions where necessary, similar to a `Decorator Pattern`.  Let me know if you are open to this and I can answer with a simple example.

Comment: @RyanStewart: All the `? extends String` parts in the code makes it pretty relevant imo.

Comment: @Keppil: The fact that there are no legal subclasses of String doesn't change the way the compiler interprets `? extends String` as a type parameter. That's exactly why I felt it was important to note its irrelevance: it's a red herring that could easily divert attention from an interesting question to which I want to see a good answer.

Comment: @Keppil: To put it another way, if you replaced all occurrences of `String` with `Number` in the question text, the same problem exists, and the same question is being asked. The `String` in the question doesn't matter at all, much less the fact that `String` is final.

Comment: @RyanStewart: I don't think we're going to agree here anytime soon. I think it is relevant, you don't.

Comment: @Keppil: It would be possible to define a language where a non-subclassable class had different behaviour in generic subtyping to a subclassable one. That would actually be pretty useful. But Java is not such a language. Which is why it's not relevant.

Comment: @cmbaxter: Thank you for your hint. It was what I actually need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Without Iterator

The easiest way is to use a *for-each loop*. Even in this case, you need the parametrize the Entry with the same wildcards as in the given map. The reason is that `Entry<? extends String, ? extends String>` is not a subtype of `Entry<String, String>`. The fact that `String` is a `final` class is irrelevant here, because the compiler has no knowledge of that.

```
for (Entry<? extends String, ? extends String> entry : m.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
}
```

### With Iterator

If you really need an Iterator, the syntax that does compile is a bit baffling:

```
Iterator<? extends Entry<? extends String, ? extends String>> iterator =
    m.entrySet().iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Entry<? extends String, ? extends String> entry = iterator.next();
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
}
```

I originally expected the iterator to be only of type `Iterator<Entry<? extends String, ? extends String>>`, which at first appears to be the return type of `iterator()` method called on a `Set<Entry<? extends String, ? extends String>>` which in turns appears to be the return type of `entrySet()` called on `Map<? extends String, ? extends String>`.

However, it is a bit more complex than that. I've found a probable answer in here:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/harmony-dev/200605.mbox/%3Cbb4674270605110156r4727e563of9ce24cdcb41a0c8@mail.gmail.com%3E

The interesting part is this:

> The problem is that the `entrySet()` method is returning a
>   `Set<Map.Entry<capture-of ? extends K, capture-of ? extends V>>`,
>   which is incompatible with the type `Set<Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>>`.
>   It's easier to describe why if I drop the `extends K` and `extends V` part.
>   So we have `Set<Map.Entry<?, ?>` and `Set<Map.Entry<capture-of ?, capture-of ?>>`.
>
> The first one, `Set<Map.Entry<?, ?>>` is a set of Map.Entries of different
>   types - ie it is a heterogeneous collection. It could contain a
>   `Map.Entry<Long, Date>` and a `Map.Entry<String, ResultSet>>` and any other
>   pair of types, all in the same set.
>
> On the other hand, `Set<Map.Entry<capture-of ?, capture-of ?>>` is a homogenous
>   collection of the same (albeit unknown) pair of types. Eg it might be a
>   `Set<Map.Entry<Long, Date>>`, so all of the entries in the set MUST be
>   `Map.Entry<Long, Date>`.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a compilable piece of code. However, I'm not sure I understand why it has to be like this.

Comment: Right, that's what I can't explain yet: why does it have to be `Iterator<? extends Entry...` instead of just `Iterator<Entry...`? I'm very curious.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart because Entry<? extends String,? extends String> is a subtype of ? extends Entry<? extends String,? extends String>. But Entry<? extends String,? extends String> is not the subtype of Entry<String, String>.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue: I think I agree with both of your statements. However a subtype relationship doesn't explain this because ["Subtyping does not extend through parameterized types"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10). By your logic, because `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`, then `Iterator<String> i1; Iterator<Object> i2 = i1;` should be valid, and we know that's not the case.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart, my argument is that your example isn't valid.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue: It's not *my* example. It's what the compiler demands.

Comment: +1 The quote does explain the issue, nice find. Ignore my earlier comment - I was reading it wrong.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart You said "By your logic ... should be valid" and I'm saying no, that is not by my logic; my logic is the complete opposite.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue: Ryan is right that none of this explains where the `Iterator<? extends ...` comes from.

Comment: @Tom Anderson Natix didn't explain where it comes from but my comment does explains where `Iterator<? extends` comes from.  And Ryan's subsequent comment isn't correct. And I'm not going to cut-and-paste Oracle's Java tutorial on generics here.

Comment: @RyanStewart See this awesome post for a further explanation of how nested wildcards work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu

Answer (score 4):

Wildcards are kind of vague, sometimes we want to turn wildcards into type variables which are more tangible.

The standard way is introducing a method with corresponding type variables

```
public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends String> m)
{
    _putAll(m);
}

<S1 extends String, S2 extends String>
void _putAll(Map<S1, S2> m)
{
    Iterator<Map.Entry<S1,S2>> iterator = m.entrySet().iterator();
}
```

In java8, also try

```
public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends String> m)
{
    m.forEach( (k,v)->
    { 
        ... 
    });
}
```

The types of (k,v) are inferred to be captured types, just like (S1,S2). However, it is also OK if we fix their types as (String,String), due to the flexibility of the signature of `forEach`

```
    m.forEach( (String k, String v)->
```

Comment: Yeah I think it was coined here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04298/index.html#3.0

Comment: It's not a very poetic name, but if it's good enough for Brian Goetz, then i guess it's good enough for me.

Comment: I refer to this as taming the wildcard. The idea is that by giving something a name, you bring it under your control - which i admit i lifted directly from [A Wizard of Earthsea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_name).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just avoid the iterator all together as this code seems to work just fine for your implementation of `putAll`:

```
for(String s: m.keySet()){
  put(s.toLowerCase(), m.get(s));
}
```

As to why you can't seem to work around that error, I have no idea.  I tried multiple variants and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: `Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends String>>` works, but I don't get why. Hoping someone has an answer.

Comment: I'm kinda hoping @Jon Skeet sees this question as I'm sure he will know what's up.  He has good insight into generics related issues.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is this: If it were possible that you could derive from `String`, say classes called `LeftRightString` and `UpDownString`, then

- `Map<LeftRightString,LeftRightString>` is a subtype of `Map<? extends String, ? extends String>`
- `Map<String, String>` is a subtype of `Map<? extends String, ? extends String>`
- but `Map<LeftRightString,LeftRightString>` is not a subtype of `Map<String,String>`

Therefore your iterator type mismatches.  If it were allowed then, the following would work when it should not work:

```
void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends String> pm) {
    Map<String, String> m = pm;
    m.add(new UpDownString(), new UpDownString());  // ooops!! if ? was LeftRightString
}
```

(Update) I want to add that almost everything I said here is in the Oracle Java tutorials so I'm baffled at why so many people keep commenting that this is wrong. And what is not in the tutorial can be found in the [Java Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). What I haven't done is give a workaround but other answers have.

Comment: Spot on. `? extends Foo` means "some particular subtype of foo which we don't know right here", which something that is *not* freely interchangeable with a simple `Foo`.

Comment: The m.add should actually be `m.put(new UpDownString(), new UpDownString());`. However, this does not answer the question why the iterator over entry set doesn't compile.

Comment: @Natrix, thanks. But I think it answers it because Map.Entry<String,String> is not the supertype of Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extend String>.

Comment: @Natix: The literal answer to the question is that it doesn't compile because the types on either side of the assignment are different, and the one on the right is not a subtype of the one on the left. This answer attempts to explain *why* it is not a subtype.

Comment: @TomAnderson: It only addresses half of the problem though: the `? extends String` vs `String` part. This is the `Entry` parameterization. But even when that's solved, there's a problem with the `Iterator` parameterization that nobody can explain yet. Why does it have to be `Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<? extends Number, ? extends Number>>` instead of just `Iterator<Map.Entry<...`?

Comment: Will m = pm even compile without a cast?

Comment: @RyanStewart: True. I can't explain the other half either. Compiler bug? By this point, i would have introduced some new type variables to tame the wildcards, after doing which the problem goes away.

Comment: That is, if you say `public <SK extends String, SV extends String> void putAll(Map<SK, SV> m) {Iterator<Map.Entry<SK, SV>> iterator = m.entrySet().iterator();}`, then that compiles. Even though that looks like it's identical to the wildcard case, just with names.

Comment: I do wonder if this is a compiler bug. I just can't see anything in the rules or the declaration of `entrySet` that would introduce a `? extends` on the the container type, rather than its type parameters.

Comment: @TomAnderson: With JDK 1.7.0_21: `java: name clash: <SK,SV>putAll(java.util.Map<SK,SV>) in org.example.HttpQueryMap and putAll(java.util.Map<? extends K,? extends V>) in java.util.HashMap have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other`.

Comment: -1 This is a subtlety, so bear with me: your answer doesn't address the actual issue here, which is related to the *nested* wildcards in `Iterator<Entry<? extends String, ? extends String>>`. You only get as far as demonstrating why generics aren't covariant.

Comment: @Paul Bellora, I don't think it matters whether or not it is nested.

Comment: It does matter. For example, this issue won't occur with `Iterator<? extends String> iterator = m_str.keySet().iterator();`.

Comment: @Paul Bellora because Iterator<String> is subtype of Iterator<? extends String>.

Comment: That's irrelevant. `Iterator<String>` doesn't figure anywhere in the problem.

Comment: @Paul Bellora I'm referring to your example: "For example, this issue won't occur with ...".  And I'm telling you why it wouldn't occur with your example.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart see my comment to Natix's answer.

Comment: `m_str.keySet().iterator()` does not return an `Iterator<String>`, but I don't have time to walk you through it anymore. I recommend you look more closely at this problem with a compiler handy, and reread Natix's answer, especially the quote at the end.

Comment: @RyanStewart: You can get around the erasure collision by pushing this code into another method. I didn't bring that up, because i thought it would be a distraction.

Comment: @Paul Bellora You should read your own comments which are contradictory. It has nothing to do with wildcards nested in types.

Comment: @Paul Bellora and I read that quote already and it makes sense because the compiler does not do a lexical replacement of <?,?> with the types that are captured in the functions argument. Otherwise what type would the local variable `List<?> x;` resolve to if the arguments to the function were `Map<?, ?>`.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue: What we're discussing is specifically related to nested wildcards. If you don't see that, then you're talking about something different than we are. This comment chain is already really long, but I'll try one more time. Please explain or link to something else that explains why `List<List<Object>> l1 = new ArrayList<>(); List<List<?>> l2 = l1;` isn't okay but `List<List<Object>> l1 = new ArrayList<>(); List<? extends List<?>> l2 = l1;` works. I sort of see the reasoning in the quote Natix found, but I still don't understand what rule makes this work.

Comment: Indeed, this is getting unwieldy. You may want to continue the conversation in [chat].