# Type mismatch after extracting expression with generic return type

Tags: java, generics, types, refactoring, capture

I stumbled upon some, at least to me, odd behaviour in Eclipse 4.4 and Java 8 build 45 when performing an extract expression refactoring. The following example shows the original and error-free code before applying the extract refactoring:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class MyMap<K, V> {
    public void putAll(final Map<? extends K, ? extends V> mapToCopy) {
        for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry : mapToCopy.entrySet()) {
        }
    }
}
```

The result of the Eclipse refactoring looks like this and leads to the error message below that refers to the read access of `entrySet` in the loop declaration:

```
    public void putAll(final Map<? extends K, ? extends V> mapToCopy) {
        Set<?> entrySet = mapToCopy.entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry : entrySet) {
                                                         ^^^^^^^^
        }
    }

Type mismatch: cannot convert 
    from element type capture#3-of ? 
    to Map.Entry<? extends K,? extends V>
```

I altered the type of the declaration of `entrySet` to `Set<Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>>`. This time, the error is indicated at the initializer of the declaration, saying:

```
    public void putAll(final Map<? extends K, ? extends V> mapToCopy) {
        Set<Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>> entrySet = mapToCopy.entrySet(); 
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry : entrySet) {
        }
    }

Type mismatch: cannot convert 
    from Set<Map.Entry<capture#1-of ? extends K,capture#2-of ? extends V>> 
    to Set<Map.Entry<? extends K,? extends V>>
```

Since the original code does compile, I am a little puzzled. Maybe someone can help me and give an explanation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that `Set<? extends Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>> entrySet = mapToCopy.entrySet(); ` will work. [JLS § 14.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) talks about translation of `Iterable` in the enhanced `for` statement. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16753901/5065475)

Comment: @AndyBrown: Can you elaborate on "Note that [...] will work", please. What do I have to modify to make it work?

Comment: In java8, also try `map.forEach( (key,value)->{ ... } )`. key/value are inferred to proper types, as some unknown subtype of K/V. The API is also flexible enough if we dictate the types - `map.forEach( (K key, V value)->{ ... } )`

Answer (score 0):

Lets first review the original source:

```
public void putAll(final Map<? extends K, ? extends V> mapToCopy) {
    for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry : mapToCopy.entrySet()) {
    }
}
```

Internally (and at Runtime), this will be compiled and will work as:

```
public void putAll(final Map mapToCopy) {
    for (Iterator<Map.Entry> iterator = mapToCopy.iterator; iterator.hasNext();) {
    }
}
```

where `? extends K` and `? extends V` will be replaced with some the real types after type erasure. The compiler will know which these type are and won't raise a `Exception` for type incompatibility.

On the other hand, if you refactor the source to this,

```
public void putAll(final Map<? extends K, ? extends V> mapToCopy) {
    Set<Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>> entrySet = mapToCopy.entrySet();
                                                    ^^^^^^^^
    for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry : entrySet) {

    }
}
```

then the compiler will have no evidence that the `entrySet` **holds** the same type as `Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>`, simply because the wildcard (`?`) always stands for something **unknown**, i.e. there's no guarantee that the wildcard from the `entrySet`'s entry key value will be the same as the `entry`'s key value (from the loop). Being not a hundred percent sure that the types are compatible, the compiler raises a compile-time error, **even though ** your may have the confidence that these types will be same at Runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Why does your third code snippet show the indicated error in the loop statement? I cannot reproduce that. In my third code snippet, the error is indicated in the declaration statement.

Comment: I think, the problem is not related to the for-loop. I elaborated on the question and started a new thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143844/type-mismatch-when-using-map-entryset).