# Why isn't a conversion to "GenericType<?>" allowed here?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

This code causes a compile error with javac (but, notably, not with Eclipse 4.2.2!):

```
public interface Foo<T> {
}

class Bar<T> implements Foo<Iterable<T>> {
}

class Test {
    void test(Foo<? extends Iterable<? extends String>> foo) {
        Bar<?> bar = (Bar<?>) foo;
    }
}
```

The error from javac is this:

```
Foo.java:9: error: inconvertible types
        Bar<?> bar = (Bar<?>) foo;
                              ^
  required: Bar<?>
  found:    Foo<CAP#1>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Iterable<? extends String> from capture of ? extends Iterable<? extends String>
```

Changing the cast to `(Bar) foo` (i.e. using the raw type) allows the code to compile, as does changing the type of `foo` to simply `Foo<? extends Iterable<?>>`.

EDIT: Hilariously, this simple change causes Eclipse to reject, but javac to accept:

```
void test(Foo<Iterable<String>> foo) {
    Bar<?> bar = (Bar<?>) foo;
}
```

And, both Eclipse and javac reject this one:

```
void test(Foo<Iterable<? extends String>> foo) {
    Bar<?> bar = (Bar<?>) foo;
}
```

Comment: Hopefully you never have to do any ugly casting like that and this is just a curiosity question...

Comment: Yes just curiosity.  The real life example was actually an instanceof check where "instanceof Bar" worked but "instanceof Bar<?>" did not.

Comment: There's some mention of it here, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

Comment: When Eclipse and javac disagree, it's usually a javac bug.

Comment: @JohanSjöberg Very interesting, but I don't think that's related to this problem specifically.  I'm not even attempting to use anything that depends on the wildcard type in this case.

Comment: @PaulBellora Well in this case there's probably a bug in both of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a programmer wants to explicitly cast a type `X` to type `Y`, the language could just allow it, assuming that the programmer knows better than the compiler.

But the good guys at Java want to prevent some obviously impossible casts, e.g. `(Cat)dog`. So they have this glorious detailed section dedicated to the subject - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1

But, are there any problems with these rules? And, do compilers conform to these rules? ... These questions are too complex and not very interesting.

What we should care is whether the cast makes sense; if it does make sense, and the compiler refuses to accept it, no problem, just work around it.

---

In your question, there are two places to insert wildcards, in `Foo< >`, and in `Iterable< >`. In each place, the wildcard can be

```
    0. None
    1. Bounded    "? extends Something"
    2. Unbounded  "?"
```

so let's explore all combinations, and here's my conclusion:

```
     wildcard#1    wildcard#2     should_compile   javac     eclipse

00   -             -              Y                Y         N
01   -             ? extends      N                N         N
02   -             ?              N                N         N
10   ? extends     -              Y                N         Y
11   ? extends     ? extends      Y                N         Y
12   ? extends     ?              Y                Y         Y
20   ?             -              Y                Y         Y
```

`should_compile` means the cast makes sense or not, explained later.

In case `10 and 11`, code should compile, but javac rejects it. Either the rules have problems, or javac has bugs.

---

Let's see for example, why case `00` makes sense and should compile

```
void test00(Foo<Iterable<String>> foo) {
    Bar<?> bar = (Bar<?>) foo;
}

the question is, could there be a class/interface `X`, such that
      Bar<X> <: Foo<Iterable<String>> 
=>    Foo<Iterable<X>> <: Foo<Iterable<String>> 
=>    Iterable<X> = Iterable<String>
=>    X = String
so the answer is yes, the cast makes sense.
```

and why case `01` should not compile

```
     Foo<Iterable<X>> <: Foo<Iterable<? extends String>>
=>   Iterable<X> = Iterable<? extends String>
=>   NO SOLUTION
     note that Iterable<String> != Iterable<? extends String>
```

and case `11`

```
     Foo<Iterable<X>>  <: Foo<? extends Iterable<? extends String>>
=>   Iterable<X> <: Iterable<? extends String>
=>   X <: String
```

---

It is surprising that case `01` should not compile, although it feels sensible. The root problem is, `Iterable` is convariant, and we ought to use a wildcard with it almost anywhere it's used. So ideally we should declare

```
class Bar<T> implements Foo<Iterable<? extends T>>
```

but life is hell if we insert wildcards everywhere. The better solution is declaration site variance. Not sure if Java will ever add that feature before we all retire.

Comment: I am surprised by case 01.  In fact I'm surprised that this isn't valid: "Foo<Iterable<? extends String>> foo = new Foo<Iterable<String>>();"

Comment: Ohhhh wow, okay, I didn't realise that Foo<Iterable<? extends String>> was a complete type.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Yeah, nested wildcards are very different from top-level wildcards: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu/3547372#3547372

Answer (score 4):

Your code is reasonable and should compile: you're narrowing the static type `Foo` to `Bar` while widening the generic type `? extends Iterable<? extends String>` to `?`, where the top-level `?` are wildcard-captures. It's a checked cast and it should compile without warning.

You should [submit an Oracle bug](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/bugreports-140511.html). I tried to search for a corresponding bug report but [this old closed ticket](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4916620) was the closest I could find to this issue (IMO the Oracle bug database is very hard to search). I'll search more when I get a chance because this javac issue feels very familiar.