# Wildcard captures/Generics

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Consider

```
class MyClass{
    List<? extends Number> nums=  new ArrayList<Integer>();
    nums.add(3.14);//Compile error
}
```

In the error's description we have: `excepted add(int, Object), found add(int,CAP#1)`. What's defenition of `CAP#1`? Why this error caused?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3546745/1065197. It is a long read but it is worth.

Comment: Here is a sound byte version that may be illuminating also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That post is about nested wildcards, which don't capture.

Comment: Have a look at the Java Tutorials article on wildcard capture: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

Answer (score 2):

This is because nums is a `List<? extends Number>`, so the compiler knows that it is a List of Number or some subclass of Number, but it does not know which. Therefore, you will never be allowed to add anything to such a list. Here's an example of what this means:

```
List<? extends Number> nums=  new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and

```
List<? extends Number> nums=  new ArrayList<Double>();
```

are both valid assignments. However, if you do:

```
nums.add(new Integer(4));
```

the compiler will not accept this as it cannot be certain that nums is a List of `Integer`.

Comment: @St.Antario: It is just something your compiler uses to internally represent the captured type variable. Basically, you see this when you have wildcards, and it represents the unknown type the wildcard represents.