# Bounded-wildcard related compiler error

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I am wondering what is wrong with this code:

```
Map <? extends String, ? extends Integer> m = null;
Set<Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends Integer>> s = m.entrySet();
```

The compiler complains with the error message:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Set<Map.Entry<capture#1-of ? extends String,capture#2-of ? extends Integer>>` to `Set<Map.Entry<? extends String,? extends Integer>>`

What should the type of `s` be? Eclipse suggests `Set<?>` but I am trying to get more specific than that.

Answer (score 9):

This issue is addressed in [this old Apache thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/harmony-dev/200605.mbox/%3Cbb4674270605110156r4727e563of9ce24cdcb41a0c8@mail.gmail.com%3E):

> The problem is that the `entrySet()` method is returning a
>   `Set<Map.Entry<capture-of ? extends K, capture-of ? extends V>>`,
>   which is incompatible with the type `Set<Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>>`.
>   It's easier to describe why if I drop the `extends K` and `extends V` part.
>   So we have `Set<Map.Entry<?, ?>` and `Set<Map.Entry<capture-of ?, capture-of ?>>`.
>
> The first one, `Set<Map.Entry<?, ?>>` is a set of Map.Entries of different
>   types - ie it is a heterogeneous collection. It could contain a
>   `Map.Entry<Long, Date>` and a `Map.Entry<String, ResultSet>>` and any other
>   pair of types, all in the same set.
>
> On the other hand, `Set<Map.Entry<capture-of ?, capture-of ?>>` is a homogenous
>   collection of the same (albeit unknown) pair of types. Eg it might be a
>   `Set<Map.Entry<Long, Date>>`, so all of the entries in the set MUST be
>   `Map.Entry<Long, Date>`.

The crux of the problem is that top-level wildcards [*capture*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html), meaning they are essentially one-off type parameters. In contrast, nested wildcards don't capture, and have somewhat of a different meaning.

So, removing the bounds for simplicity, declaring

```
Map<?, ?> m;
```

means "a map of some *specific* unknown type of keys and some *specific* unknown type of values".

But declaring

```
Set<Map.Entry<?, ?>> s;
```

means "a set of entries of any type of key and value".

So that's where you run into trouble because the expression `m.entrySet()` doesn't want to return that but instead "a set of entries of some *specific* unknown type of keys and some *specific* unknown type of values". And those types are incompatible because generics [aren't covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p): A `Set<Type>` isn't a `Set<SuperType>`.

(See this fascinating post, which helps tease apart the nuances of nested wildcards: [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu).)

One workaround is to use a [*capture helper*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04298/index.html#3.0) method, which takes advantage of the fact that formal type parameters can be nested:

```
private <K extends String, V extends Integer> void help(final Map<K, V> map) {
    final Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries = map.entrySet();
    // logic
}

...

Map<? extends String, ? extends Integer> m = null;
help(m);
```

That's a contrived example since `String` and `Integer` are both `final`, but it shows the concept.

A simpler workaround is the following:

```
Set<? extends Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends Integer>> s = m.entrySet();
```

This means adding non-`null` elements to `s` isn't allowed, but in the case of the `Set` returned by `entrySet`, the `add` and `addAll` methods are unsupported anyway (thanks to newacct for [clarifying this point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907262/bounded-wildcard-related-compiler-error/18907402?noredirect=1#comment27943720_18907402)).

Comment: "This effectively makes s read-only but contextually that shouldn't be an issue." Technically, it only makes it not possible to add (non-`null`) things to it; removal is still allowed. This is guaranteed not to be an issue -- the documentation for `entrySet()` says that the returned `Set` "does not support the add or addAll operations."

Comment: @newacct You're right, "read-only" was a problematic description - fixed.

Comment: Yeah. I also think the signature of the `entrySet()` method in the Java API is a mistake. `Set<? extends Map.Entry<...>>` is sufficient, and it makes it more flexible for the implementation of the Map to, for example, return a set that is parameterized by a custom entry subclass or something.

Comment: Another solution is to explicitly use an unmodifiable set: `Set<Map.Entry<?, ?>> set = Collections.<Map.Entry<?, ?>>unmodifiableSet(entries.entrySet())`