# Java generics collection wildcard capture

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I understand that the intricacies of Java generics can get... intricate. I figure that if I have a Google Guava multimap with a `Collection<? extends FooBar>`, I should be able to use `getMap()` to assign that to a `Map<String, ? extends FooBar>`. But I can't do that in Eclipse 4.4RC2; it tells me, "Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Map<String,Collection<capture#1-of ? extends EclipseGenerics.FooBar>>` to `Map<String,Collection<? extends EclipseGenerics.FooBar>>`".

```
import java.util.*;

import com.google.common.collect.*;

public class EclipseGenerics {

  public static interface FooBar {
    public String getFoo();
  }

  public static <FB extends FooBar> SetMultimap<String, FB> groupFooBarByBar(final Iterable<FB> foobars) {
    final SetMultimap<String, FB> groupedFoobars = HashMultimap.create();
    for (final FB foobar : foobars) {
      groupedFoobars.put(foobar.getFoo(), foobar);
    }
    return groupedFoobars;
  }

  public static void test() {
    Collection<FooBar> foobars = new ArrayList<>();
    final SetMultimap<String, ? extends FooBar> groupedFooBars = groupFooBarByBar(foobars);
    //why can't I do this?
    final Map<String, Collection<? extends FooBar>> map = groupedFooBars.asMap();
  }

}
```

I cannot do this:

```
final Map<String, Collection<? extends FooBar>> map = groupedFooBars.asMap();
```

Why not? `asMap()` should return `Map<K,Collection<V>>`.

But I can do this!

```
final Map<String, ? extends Collection<? extends FooBar>> map = groupedFooBars.asMap();
```

I get a similar error with Oracle's Java 1.8 javac compiler, so either Eclipse 4.4RC2 and Oracle are both wrong, or (more likely) I'm still not a complete expert on Java generics.

Anyone care to explain why `Map<String, Collection<? extends FooBar>>` doesn't work, but `Map<String, ? extends Collection<? extends FooBar>>` does work?

Comment: I retract my previous comment ... Now that I see what you're doing, I agree.. That's wrong.

Comment: What type does `asMap()` return? Based on your final two lines of code, I think Eclipse is right... I have to admit though that the error that Eclipse is making doesn't really make a whole lot of sense to me -- not really sure where that `capture#1` came from...

Comment: `asMap()` returns `Map<K,Collection<V>>`.

Comment: What happens if you try `javac`?

Comment: hehe I was just getting to that. I'm doing a Maven-based build now and... Oracle's Java 1.8.0 javac says the same thing. I still don't understand why, but at least Oracle and Eclipse are in agreement here.

Comment: Hmmm, if `javac` and Eclipse agree it's likely that this is proper behavior... Unfortunately, I'm just as confuzzled as you are as to why this doesn't work. Is the returned error message the same?

Comment: Pretty much the same error message, yes.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907262/bounded-wildcard-related-compiler-error.

Comment: @unholysampler, you seem to be correct that this is a duplicate, but not for the post you provided. pingw33n provided the correct post. Please edit your duplicate flag to indicate the correct post.

Comment: I think we need a Moderator to do that.  Otherwise we have to reopen the question and close it again.