# Wildcard for Set in Map - return type incompatible - Why?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, wildcard, return-type

The following is an example code to set up my problem situation:

**Foo interface:**

```
interface Foo<K> {

    Map<K, Set<? extends Foo<K>>> map();
    Set<? extends Foo<K>> set(); }
```

**Bar interface:**

```
interface Bar<K> extends Foo<K> {}
```

**FooBar class** (alternative 1):

```
class FooBar<K> implements Bar<K> {

    Map<K, Set<Bar<K>>> map;
    Set<Bar<K>> set;

    @Override
    public Map<K, Set<? extends Foo<K>>> map() {
        return map; }

    // For the above, Eclipse is yelling:
    // Type mismatch: cannot convert from 
    // Map<K,Set<Bar<K>>> to Map<K,Set<? extends Foo<K>>>

    // But Eclipse likes the following:
    @Override
    public Set<? extends Foo<K>> set() {
        return set; }  
}
```

**FooBar class** (alternative 2):

```
class FooBar<K> implements Bar<K> {

    Map<K, Set<Bar<K>>> map;
    Set<Bar<K>> set;

    @Override
    public Map<K, Set<Bar<K>>> map() {
        return map; }

    // For the above, Eclipse is yelling:
    // The return type is incompatible with Foo<K>.map()

    // But Eclipse, again, likes the following:
    @Override
    public Set<Bar<K>> set() {
        return set; }  
}
```

In alternative 1 and 2 I use Bar as the wildcard match for "? extends Foo". It works for the set() method but it does not work for the map() method. Can somebody explain to me why it behaves like that and if there is a workaround?

Comment: See also: [Bounded-wildcard related compiler error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907262/bounded-wildcard-related-compiler-error), [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original example is complicated, I will use some simplifications

In your example `Foo.set()` returns `Set<? extends X>`

If `Y extends X` then `Set<Y>` **IS** `Set<? extends X>`

But `Foo.map()` returns `Map<K, Set<? extends X>>` and

`Map<K, Set<Y>>` **IS NOT** `Map<K, Set<? extends X>>` however

`Map<K, Set<Y>>` **IS**  `Map<K, ? extends Set<? extends X>>`

Compare with the following

```
Number number5 = 5;
Integer int5 = 5;
number5 = int5;  //OK

List<Number> listNumber5 = Arrays.asList(number5);
List<Integer> listInt5 = Arrays.asList(int5);
listNumber5 = listInt5; //ERROR

List<? extends Number> listExtendsNumber5 = Arrays.asList(number5);
listExtendsNumber5 = listInt5; // OK
```

Generics are not easy to explain, I did my best. If something is not clear , add question as comment