# Generics - Java collection within a collection

Tags: java, generics, collections, nested

I'm new to generics, so not sure where I'm going wrong...

I have classes, called Cat, Dog and Rabbit, which implement the interface Animal.

The following code will compile

```
Set<? extends Animal> animalSet;
Set<Dog> dogSet = new HashSet<Dog>();
animalSet = dogSet;
```

But the following code will not

```
Map<String, Set<? extends Animal>> animalMap;
Map<String, Set<Dog>> dogMap = new HashMap<String, Set<Dog>>();
animalMap = dogMap; // this line will not compile
```

The compiler says the types are incompatible. Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for everyone's help

I've changed the first line of code by adding another wildcard
The following code will compile

```
Map<String, ? extends Set<? extends Animal>> animalMap;
Map<String, Set<Dog>> dogMap = new HashMap<String, Set<Dog>>();
animalMap = dogMap;
```

See also the solution given by Cyrille Ka below - use putAll() to transfer values from dogMap to animalMap, instead of assigning dogMap to animalMap.

Comment: Here a parent child relationship does not work as in Parent p = child.

Comment: related: [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu)

Comment: You need to go deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to your problem is this one:

```
Map<String, ? extends Set<? extends Animal>> animalMap;
Map<String, Set<Dog>> dogMap = new HashMap<String, Set<Dog>>();
animalMap = dogMap;
```

because `Set<Dog>` is not a `Set<? extends Animal>`, but rather extends it.

Answer (score 7):

Basically, when you write:

```
Map<String, Set<? extends Animal>> animalMap;
```

You declare that any value of the map is a set that can contain any object whose type is a subclass of Animal. Then it would be perfectly reasonable for a client code to write:

```
animalMap.put("miaow", aCatSet);
```

where `acatSet` is a `Set<Cat>`.

But `dogMap` can not accept a `Set<Cat>` as value, it can only accept `Set<Dog>`. Therefore there is a possibility of type incompatibility and that's why this construction is forbidden.

**Edit**: As for how to fix that, it depends on what you want to do. If you have a `dogMap` somewhere and want to put its content into `animalMap` then you can simply copy the content like this:

```
Map<String, Set<? extends Animal>> animalMap = new HashMap<String, Set<? extends Animal>>();
Map<String, Set<Dog>> dogMap = new HashMap<String, Set<Dog>>();

/// fill dogMap

animalMap.putAll(dogMap);
```

Comment: P.S. Thanks for the edit, that's quite a neat little solution
f only I'd realised how simple it was...

Comment: @claire Your question was *Where am I going wrong?* not how to fix ;)

Answer (score 3):

Because Java is strongly typed: `? extends Animal` is not `Dog`, it could be `Cat`, or another subclass.

For example, in this case, if you define `Set<? extends Animal> animalSet`, I can legally do `animalSet.add(new Cat())`, right?. But you want to initialize this `animalSet` with a `Set<Dog>`, which would not allow `animalSet.add(new Cat())` anymore. This is inconsisent, and this is why it is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

As for why - let me get back on that later. 
For now note that this compiles:

```
Map<String, Set<? extends Animal>> animalMap;
Map<String, Set<? extends Animal>> dogMap 
    = new HashMap<String, Set<? extends Animal>>();
Set<Dog> dogMapVal = new HashSet<Dog>();
dogMap.put("fido", dogMapVal);
animalMap = dogMap;
```

Comment: Thanks. I can understand why your code compiles. But I wanted "dogMap" to just contain sets of dogs, perform some operations on it which are just relative to dogs not all animals, then assign it to "animalMap" later.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the following logic (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu/#answer-3547372)) to your question :

- `Dog`  **IS**  `Animal`
- `Set<Dog>`  **IS**  `Set<? extends Animal>`
- `Map<String, Dog>`  **IS NOT**  `Map<String, Animal>`

Therefore :

- `Map<String, Set<Dog>>`  **IS NOT**  `Map<String, Set<? extends Animal>>`

That is what compiler complains about in your last assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here a parent child relationship does not work as in Parent p = child. [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse the Dog not equals Animal, only extends it.

Image, if there a code where You use somewhere this code, where You put dogs in it. after , somwwhere again yout wold like to use it again, you thinks you put dog here, so you got back dogs. But if someone, put Cats or Rabbits to it?

So this is why.