# Capture conversion is not applied recursively?

Tags: java, generics

I was going through the concept of capture conversion from [JLS §5.1.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10), and came across this statement:

> Capture conversion is not applied recursively.

Unfortunately there is no example there to explain what it really means, and I'm having hard time understand it. I also went through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3546745), but that too doesn't go into detail of recursive capture. Can someone explain with some example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capture conversion is only applied on the 1st level wildcards.

For example, if an object is of type `List<? extends X>`, we know the object is also a `List<T>` for some `T` that is a subtype of `X`.

However, if an object is of type `List<List<?>>`, it is not a `List<List<T>>` for some `T`.

A `List<? extends List<?>>` can be capture-converted to `List<T>` for some `T` that is subtype of `List<?>`. However the 2nd `?` cannot be eliminated.