# Difference of assignability with nested wildcards in Java 7/8 generics

Tags: java, generics, java-8, bounded-wildcard

The following compiles just fine in JDK8, but gives an *incompatible types* error with JDK7.

```
List<List<? extends Number>> xs = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(0));
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3547372/1427124), `List<List<? extends Number>>` doesn't have a supertype relationship to `List<List<Integer>>`.

What changed in Java 8 that made this assignment work? I'm also having a hard time understanding why it *doesn't* work in Java 7.

---

Both of these statements compile without type error using JDK7:

```
List<? extends Number> xs = Arrays.asList(0);
List<? extends List<? extends Number>> ys = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(0));
```

It seems very unintuitive to me that both of those work in JDK7, but the original example above does not. All of them of course will work in JDK8. I think to really understand what's going on here I'd need to understand why these examples are legal in Java 7 but the original example is not.

Comment: Seems to me that because `Arrays.asList(0)` would return a `List<Integer>`, and `Arrays.asList()` of that would return a `List` whose elements are `List<Integer>`, seems to me that the assignment `List<List<? extends Number>>` would actually be right... I'm almost certainly misunderstanding something though

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Aaaaand turns out I forgot to change the line back from when I was experimenting with it. I get failures too.

Comment: @user3580294 - _"... seems to me that the assignment List<List<? extends Number>> would actually be right..."_ That's exactly what I'm confused about. The Java 8 behavior seems like the intuitively correct behavior to me, so I don't understand why there's a type error in Java 7. What's the rationale behind that? Apparently they decided to fix it in Java 8, but I can't figure out what exactly they changed to make this work.

Comment: @DaoWen I've heard that there were improvements in the JLS as to how type inference/detection/checking works in Java 8, so it could be possible that the spec didn't allow for it back then. I can't say for sure though. Quite an intriguing question....

Comment: The correct idiom for Java 7 would be `List<List<? extends Number>> ys = Arrays.<List<? extends Number>asList(Arrays.asList(0));`. It shows that even under Java 7 the assignment is correct and only an issue of the limited *type-inference*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this has to do with [invocation contexts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) and [widening reference conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5).

Basically, in that invocation context, the type of the argument `0` in `Arrays.asList(0)` can be boxed to `Integer` and then widened to `Number`. When that happens, `Arrays.asList(0)` has a return type of `List<Number>`. Through the same process, that `List<Number>` can be converted to `List<? extends Number>` before being used as an argument to the outer `Arrays.asList(..)`.

This is equivalent to using explicit type arguments in Java 7

```
List<List<? extends Number>> xs = Arrays.<List<? extends Number>>asList(Arrays.<Number>asList(0));
```

---

In Java 7, the type of an expression is the same regardless of where it is used, whether it's a standalone expression or used in assignment expression.

Java 8 introduced [poly-expressions](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~dlsmith/jsr335-0.6.1/D.html) in which the type of the expression could be influenced by the target type of the expression.

For example, in the following assignment expression

```
List<Number> numbers = Arrays.asList(1);
```

The type of the expression `Arrays.asList(1)` is the return type of the method being invoked which depends entirely on the generic type parameter. In this case, that type argument will be inferred as `Integer` because the value `1` can be converted to `Integer` through boxing conversion (primitives can't be used with generics). So the type of the expression is `List<Integer>`.

In Java 7, this assignment expression would not compile because `List<Integer>` cannot be assigned to `List<Number>`. This could be fixed by providing an explicit type argument when invoking `asList`

```
List<Number> numbers = Arrays.<Number>asList(1);
```

in which case, the method invocation expects a `Number` argument for its first parameter and the value `1` satisfies that.

In Java 8, the assignment expression is a [poly expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)

> A method invocation expression is a poly expression if all of the
>   following are true:
>
> - The invocation appears in an **assignment context** or an invocation context (§5.2, §5.3).
> - If the invocation is qualified (that is, any form of `MethodInvocation` except for the first), then the **invocation elides `TypeArguments` to the left of the Identifier**.
> - **The method to be invoked, as determined by the following subsections, is generic (§8.4.4) and has a return type that mentions at least one of the method's type parameters.**

Being a poly expression, it can be influenced by the type of the variable it is being assigned to. And that's what happens. The generic type `Number` influences the type argument inferred in the invocation of `Arrays.asList(1)`.

Note how it wouldn't work in the following example

```
List<Number> numbers = ...;
List<Integer> integers = ...; // integers is not a poly expression
numbers = integers; // nope
```

So it's not covariance, but we get some of its benefits in some places.

Comment: How in the world do you find these things buried in the JLS?

Comment: @user3580294 I recently read part of an article by Angelika Langer that spoke about invocation contexts (although I think it was before they were applied in Java 8). I remembered the term and just `ctrl+f`'ed.

Comment: I don't see any significant differences in the sections you've linked between Java 7 and 8: [(Java 7) Method Invocation Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) and [(Java 7) Widening Reference Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5). Also note that I've updated my question with a couple more examples.

Comment: @Dao Then I should also add [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). Basically, that invocation is a poly expression, where a poly expression [can be influenced by the target type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.3) of the expression.

Comment: @DaoWen I'm at work right now, but I'll get back to it later if you don't have the answers you seek.

Comment: @DaoWen I've added some details. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite simple:

In Java 7, the context of a method call was not considered when inferring type arguments. The only thing that was considered where the arguments of a method call.

In your case, `int` is boxed to `Integer` which yields `List<Integer>` as type for the inner call and then `List<List<Integer>>` as type for the outer call. Now you have a problem, since you want to assign the result to a variable of type `List<List<? extends Number>>` and this is just not possible since generics are invariant as long as there are no wildcards used, i.e., `List<X>` can never be converted to `List<Y>`. In your case `X` is `List<Integer>` and `Y` is `List<? extends Number>`. Even if `List<? extends Number>` contains a wildcard, it does not use a wildcard itself, i.e., it is not `? extends List<? extends Number>`. This is why it does not compile in Java 7.

I know understanding generics and variance and wildcards is not that easy. Maybe I can clarify it like this for you:

1. Usually, `A<Y>` is never considered a subtype of any `A<Z>`.
2. However, if `Z` inherits from `Y`, then `A<Z>` is a subtype of `A<? extends Y>`.
3. Now to the nested generics: We do know, that the inner types (`A<Z>` and `A<? extends Y>` are related in a subtype relation. But if we wrap them in another generic type, like `B<A<Z>>` and `B<A<? extends Y>>` then rule 1. applies: Since there are no wildcards, the second `B` is not considered a subtype of the first one. If we again introduce a wildcard, then they are: `B<A<Z>>` is indeed a subtype of `B<? extends A<? extends Y>>`. But now note that the outher `? extends` is missing in your example, so it does not compile in Java 7.

Now to Java 8. Java 8 also takes the *context* of a call into account when inferring type arguments. Thus, Java 8 considers that you want to pass the result of the `Arrays.asList` calls to a variable of type `List<List<? extends Number>>`. It therefore tries to find type arguments that will make this assignment legal. It then infers that the type argument for the inner call must be `Number`, cause otherwise the assignment would not be legal.

To cut it short: Java 8 is just a lot more clever than Java 7 when choosing type arguments, since it also looks at the context, not only the arguments.

Comment: Isn't a `List<Integer>` a `List<? extends Number>` though? I thought wildcards allow for covariance such as this.

Comment: `List<? extends Number> xs = Arrays.asList(0);` compiles without error with JDK7. Doesn't that contradict your answer? (Note that I've updated my question with this example.)

Comment: @user3580294: They do! But wildcards are not transitive. Just because `List<Integer>` is a `List<? extends Number>` does not mean that List<List<Integer>>` is a `List<List<? extends Number>>`.

Comment: @DaoWen: Look at my comment above. I have clarified my answer. The problem are the *nested* generics.

Comment: Ah, that's true. Looks like I got the lists backwards. Thanks!

Comment: I feel like Sotirios answered my core question, but you cleared up my confusion about the wildcards. To try to be fair, I'm upvoting your answer, but accepting (and not upvoting) the other answer.