# Why can't I pass a list of children into a method that accepts List<? extends Parent>?

Tags: java, generics

I have a class named `FamilyHistoryPersonModel` that extends a class named `PersonModel`.

```
    MapValue mapValue = new MapValue("relatives",
            new GenericType<FamilyHistoryPersonModel>() {},
            new GenericType<List<FamilyHistoryPersonModel>>() {}  //error here
    );
```

Constructor:

```
    private MapValue(String pluralUrl, GenericType<? extends PersonModel> singleResultGenericType, GenericType<List<? extends PersonModel>> listResultGenericType) {
        this.pluralUrl = pluralUrl;
        this.singleResultGenericType = singleResultGenericType;
        this.listResultGenericType = listResultGenericType;
    }
```

Error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor MapValue(java.lang.String,<anonymous com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType<com.models.FamilyHistoryPersonModel>>,<anonymous com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType<java.util.List<com.models.FamilyHistoryPersonModel>>>)
location: class com.rest.v2.resource.CreatePersonModelIntegrationTest.MapValue
```

Why am I getting this error?  How do I fix it?  I don't want to change the constructor to accept `GenericType<List<FamilyHistoryPersonModel>> listResultGenericType`

I am using JDK 1.6

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Just as a `List<Dog>` is not a `List<Animal>` even if `Animal` subclasses `Dog`, a `GenericType<List<FamilyHistoryPersonModel>>` is not a `GenericType<List<? extends PersonModel>>`, even if a `List<FamilyHistoryPersonModel>` is a `List<? extends PersonModel>`.

The solution is to provide a wildcard at the top-level generic type parameter.  In the `MapValue` constructor, change the parameter from

```
GenericType<List<? extends PersonModel>> listResultGenericType
```

to

```
GenericType<? extends List<? extends PersonModel>> listResultGenericType
```

I assume that you will also need to change the type of `this.listResultGenericType` to match.

Comment: FYI - I think this was "fixed" in JDK8: [Difference of assignability with nested wildcards in Java 7/8 generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188824).

Comment: That works, but I don't get why I have to do it.  Why isn't a `List<Dog>` a `List<Animal>`?

Comment: @tieTYT - *"That works, but I don't get why I have to do it. Why isn't a List<Dog> a List<Animal>?"* That's **exactly** what [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188824) (linked to in my comment above) was asking.

Comment: @tieTYT Java generic types are invariant, where you're expecting them to be covariant.  For more detail, please see [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p).

Comment: @rgettman ok that was helpful.  That explains why they are not the same thing.  But I still don't get why `<? extends List<? extends PersonModel>>` fixes the problem.

Comment: Without that first `? extends`, then the generic type parameter for the inner `List` _must_ be `? extends PersonModel`, to match the paramter's generic type, because Java generics are invariant.  To be able to substitute `FamilyHistoryPersonModel` in the generic type parameter for `List`, you must `? extends` on the `List`,  for the same reason that you must use `List<? extends Animal>` to be able to supply a `List<Dog>`.  Without that `? extends`, then generic type parameter must match exactly, because of the invariance of generics here.