# incompatible types error when using generics and reflection

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, reflection, types

Let: `B extends A`;

Can somebody tell me why this code:

```
List<Class<? extends A>> l = Arrays.asList(B.class);
```

Throws me the following error when trying to compile:

```
error: incompatible types: List<Class<B>> cannot be converted to List<Class<? extends A>>
```

while this code:

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends A>> l = new ArrayList<Class<? extends A>>();
l.add(B.class);
```

works perfectly fine?

Comment: Upgrade to Java 8 for your first snippet to work.

Comment: I won't close as duplicate because the answers don't address your second question, but read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188824/difference-of-assignability-with-nested-wildcards-in-java-7-8-generics).

Answer (score 2):

As per [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) the `Arrays.asList(..)` method takes as its parameter variable(s) of the same type and returns the list of that type.

> `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)`

If `Class<B>` is bond to type `T` then the method return type is `List<Class<B>>` which is **NOT** type `List<Class<? extends A>>` as expected. Thus the compile error occurs.

It can be fixed by adding the explicit cast as below:

```
List<Class<? extends A>> l = Arrays.<Class<? extends A>>asList(B.class);
```

**EDITED**
As mentioned by Sotirios **Java 8** has resolved that tedious issue with introduction of [poly expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24190057/4454454).