# java 7 heterogeneous containers assignability

Tags: java, generics

The following Java 7 code compiles fine without type safety warnings:

```
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class Foo {
    public static class Bar<T> {
        public final Class<T> type;

        public Bar(Class<T> type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo(
                Arrays.asList(
                        new Bar<>(Object.class),
                        new Bar<>(String.class)));
    }

    public final List<Bar<?>> list;

    public Foo(List<Bar<?>> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

However, changing

```
new Bar<>(Object.class),
```

to

```
new Bar<>(String.class),
```

fails to compile with following error:

```
The constructor Foo(List<Foo.Bar<String>>) is undefined
```

Compiling with Java 8 succeeds. According to previous posts on StackOverflow

- [Difference of assignability with nested wildcards in Java 7/8 generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188824/difference-of-assignability-with-nested-wildcards-in-java-7-8-generics)
- [Why does this compile in Java7 and does not in Java8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269055/why-does-this-compile-in-java7-and-does-not-in-java8)

there was some improvement in Java 8 which now allows this to compile.

The question is now what could be the best workaround for Java 7.

Adrian.

Comment: Aside: you'd get a StackOverflowError if this did compile.

Comment: Compile fine @Andy Turne

Comment: @PSM please post an answer rather than dumping unreadable code in comments.

Comment: @PSM not for OP: question states "fails to compile".

Comment: There is no answer as code compile fine.I put the same code for ref. purpose. I just change new Bar<>(Object.class)  to new Bar<>(String.class).

Comment: I copied your code into Eclipse. The Eclipse compiler does not show any error or warning. Additionally, I compiled it then using "javac" (JDK 1.8.0_77). Again it compiles without any error or warning. So, please show us also how you compile this and with which Java version.

Comment: Then write "the code compiles for me" rather than dumping code in a comment. It is unclear what you are saying with the current comment.

Comment: yes It is true @ Seelenvirtuose.No compile time error or warning.

Comment: Ok @ Andy Turner.But Why you told that "you'd get a StackOverflowError if this did compile".

Comment: I tried it also now with Java 7 (JDK 1.7.0_80). There I get the mentioned error, in Eclipse and with "javac". So it is about the Java version.

Comment: @PSM - Because it will.  See the instance initializer block?

Comment: The StackOverflowError  is not the issue... Replaced the instance initializer block with a static main method; same compilation issue.

Comment: Tried now with Java 8 and it works; seems like a limitation/defect in Java 7.

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188824/difference-of-assignability-with-nested-wildcards-in-java-7-8-generics

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269055/why-does-this-compile-in-java7-and-does-not-in-java8

Comment: Question is now... Is there an workaround? I will re-edit the question shortly.

Comment: @AdrianHerscu Workaround is to declare a `List<? extends Bar<?>> list` (if possible).

Comment: Great! Seems that it works.