# Java wildcard parameterized type incompatible

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

When I try to assign an object of type `List<List<Object>>` to a variable with a wildcard parameterized type `List<List<?>>`, I get the error "*incompatible types: `List<List<Object>>` cannot be converted to `List<List<?>>`*".

Example:

```
List<List<Object>> x = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<?>> y = x;   // Error
```

On the other hand, assigning an object of type `List<Object>` to a variable of type `List<?>` work perfectly fine.

Example:

```
List<Object> x = new ArrayList<>();
List<?> y = x;   // Works fine
```

Why is that? Why does it work for `List<?>` but not for `List<List<?>>`?

Environment: JDK 7, Netbeans 8

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Sorry, that I didn't find this by myself. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3547372/104976 perfectly answers my question.

Comment: No problem! No need to apologize. I had just seen it before so I knew what I was looking for.