# Java Generics: assignment with nested wildcard parameters

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter, nested-generics

For the following code sample:

```
public static class Abc<X> { }
public static class Def<Y> { }
public static class Ghi<Z> { }

public void doThis() {
    List<?> listOne;
    List<Abc<?>> listTwo;
    List<Abc<Def<?>>> listThree;
    List<Abc<Def<Ghi<?>>>> listFour;
    List<Abc<Def<Ghi<String>>>> listFive;

    Abc<Def<Ghi<String>>> abcdef;

    abcdef = new Abc<Def<Ghi<String>>>();

    listOne.add(abcdef);    // line 1
    listTwo.add(abcdef);    // line 2
    listThree.add(abcdef);  // line 3
    listFour.add(abcdef);   // line 4
    listFive.add(abcdef);   // line 5
}
```

Lines 1, 3, and 4 do not compile:

*(line 1)*

```
The method add(capture#1-of ?) in the type List<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Abc<Def<Ghi<String>>>)
```

*(line 3)*

```
The method add(Abc<Def<?>>) in the type List<Abc<Def<?>>> is not applicable for the arguments (Abc<Def<Ghi<String>>>)
```

*(line 4)*

```
The method add(Abc<Def<Ghi<?>>>) in the type List<Abc<Def<Ghi<?>>>> is not applicable for the arguments (Abc<Def<Ghi<String>>>)
```

Lines 2 and 5, however, compile.

Could anyone explain why lines 1, 3, and 4 are not legal assignments?  And if wildcard parameters cannot be used in that way on those lines, then why is the assignment on line 2 legal?

Comment: Extremely good question! For *line 1*, it is because you cannot add anything to a list of unknown type except `null`.

Comment: [related...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58631449/1059372)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`listOne.add(abcdef)` (line 1) is invalid because `List<?>` represents a list of some unknown specific type. For example, it could be a `List<String>`, so we wouldn't want to add anything that isn't a `String`. The compiler error happens because `Abc<Def<Ghi<String>>>` is not assignable to `?`.

`listTwo.add(abcdef)` (line 2) is valid because `List<Abc<?>>` represents a list of `Abc`s of *any type*. That's right - *nested* wildcards are different from top-level wildcards in that they represent any type rather than some specific type (in other words, nested wildcards don't [*capture*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html)). The compiler allows it because `Abc<Def<Ghi<String>>>` is assignable to `Abc<?>`. See this post for further discussion of nested wildcards: [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu)

`listThree.add(abcdef)` (line 3) is invalid because `List<Abc<Def<?>>>` represents a list of `Abc`s of `Def`s of any type. Generics are not covariant, so `Abc<Def<Ghi<String>>>` is not assignable to `Abc<Def<?>>`, even though `Def<Ghi<String>>` is assignable to `Def<?>`. A `List<Integer>` isn't assignable to a `List<Number>` for the same reason. See this post for further explanation: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

`listFour.add(abcdef)` (line 4) is invalid for the same reason - `Abc<Def<Ghi<String>>>` is not assignable to `Abc<Def<Ghi<?>>>`.

`listFive.add(abcdef)` (line 5) is valid because the generic types match exactly - `Abc<Def<Ghi<String>>>` is obviously assignable to `Abc<Def<Ghi<String>>>`.

Comment: Wanted to follow-up to note that the assignability problems of lines 3 and 4 can be resolved by changing the declarations from `List<Abc<Def<?>>> listThree` to `List<Abc<? extends Def<?>>> listThree` and from `List<Abc<Def<Ghi<?>>>>` to `List<Abc<? extends Def<? extends Ghi<?>>>> listFour`. Thanks for the concise explanation and useful links; it's much clearer now.

Comment: @PaulBellora _That's right - nested wildcards are different from top-level wildcards in that they represent any type rather than some specific type_ this! very much this!