# Why does Java type inference for generic supertypes break here?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Given this Java code:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleEntry<Integer, String> simpleEntry = new SimpleEntry<>(1, "1");
        Optional<Entry<Integer, String>> optionalEntry = Optional.of(simpleEntry);
        Optional<SimpleEntry<Integer, String>> optionalSimpleEntry = Optional.of(simpleEntry);

        List<Entry<Integer, String>> list1 = Arrays.asList(simpleEntry);
        List<Optional<Entry<Integer, String>>> list2 = Arrays.asList(optionalEntry);
        List<Optional<SimpleEntry<Integer, String>>> list3 = Arrays.asList(optionalSimpleEntry);
        List<Optional<Entry<Integer, String>>> list4 = Arrays.asList(optionalSimpleEntry);
    }
}
```

The expressions initializing `list`, `list2` and `list3` work fine. However, the expression initializing `list4` breaks with this error in Eclipse:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Optional<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer,String>>>
to List<Optional<Map.Entry<Integer,String>>>
```

and this error in `javac`:

```
Test.java:16: error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
        List<Optional<Entry<Integer, String>>> list4 = Arrays.asList(optionalSimpleEntry);
                                                                    ^
    equality constraints: Optional<Entry<Integer,String>>
    lower bounds: Optional<SimpleEntry<Integer,String>>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>asList(T...)
```

But `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` directly implements `Map.Entry`. So why does type inference break for `list4` when it works for `list1` to `list3` (and also for the assignment to `optionalEntry`, for that matter)?

Particularly I don't understand why the assignment to `list1` works when the assignment to `list4` does not.

Comment: even [easier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902219/nested-wildcards/58631449#58631449) explained...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you understand why `Optional<SimpleEntry<Integer,String>>` cannot be assigned to a variable of type `List<Optional<Entry<Integer, String>>>`. If not, please read the Q&A [Is List a subclass of List? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po?rq=1)

However, your question why the `list1` declaration works but the `list4` declaration.

There is a difference between the `list1` and `list4` declarations. For `list1`, the form is:

```
SimpleEntry<Integer, String> simpleEntry = ...;
List<Entry<Integer, String>> list = Arrays.asList<T>(simpleEntry);
```

In this case, the type variable `T` of the `Arrays.asList` method is not fixed to a particular type yet. It has an upper bound of `SimpleEntry<Integer, String>` (the type of `simpleEntry`).

According to the [Java Language Specification, section 18.5.2, "Invocation Type Inference"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2), the compiler will further constraint the type `T` by constraining the return type of `asList` (`List<T>`) to the invocation context target type (`List<Entry<Integer, String>>`).

This is possible; when the compiler selects T to be `Entry<Integer, String>`, the whole expression fits, because a value of type `SimpleEntry<Integer, String>` can be assigned to a variable of type `Entry<Integer, String>`.

For `list4`, the form is:

```
SimpleEntry<Integer, String> simpleEntry = new SimpleEntry<>(1, "1");
Optional<SimpleEntry<Integer, String>> optionalSimpleEntry = Optional.of(simpleEntry);
List<Optional<Entry<Integer, String>>> list4 = Arrays.asList<T>(optionalSimpleEntry);
```

Here, `T` is initially constrained to an upper bound of `Optional<SimpleEntry<Integer, String>>`. The target type of the expression context is `List<Optional<Entry<Integer, String>>>`. It is not possible for the compiler to come up with a `T` that fits both.

A value of type `Optional<SimpleEntry<Integer, String>>` cannot be assigned to a variable of type `Optional<Entry<Integer, String>>>`.

That's why the compiler complains.

### In simpler terms

In simpler terms, for a method where the generic type is not constrained, and there is an expression context that constrains the generic type, it works for one level deep of parameterization.

You can say

```
Dog dog = ...;
List<Animal> animals = Arrays.asList(dog);
```

But it doesn't work at a deeper level of parameterization.

```
Optional<Dog> optionalDog = ...;
List<Optional<Animal>> optionalAnimals = Arrays.asList(optionalDog);
```

Answer (score 2):

So let's explicitly write the types we expect to infer. Also, we'll put the declaration near the use.

```
SimpleEntry<Integer, String> simpleEntry = ...
List<Entry<Integer, String>> list1 =
    Arrays.<Entry<Integer, String>>asList(simpleEntry);
```

`SimpleEntry<xyz>` is an `Entry<xyz>` so that is fine.

```
Optional<Entry<Integer, String>> optionalEntry = ...
List<Optional<Entry<Integer, String>>> list2 =
    Arrays.<Optional<Entry<Integer, String>>>asList(optionalEntry);
```

`Optional<xyz>` is trivially an `Optional<xyz>`.

```
Optional<SimpleEntry<Integer, String>> optionalSimpleEntry = ...
List<Optional<SimpleEntry<Integer, String>>> list3 =
    Arrays.<Optional<SimpleEntry<Integer, String>>>asList(optionalSimpleEntry);
```

`Optional<xyz>` is trivially an `Optional<xyz>` again.

```
Optional<SimpleEntry<Integer, String>> optionalSimpleEntry = ...
List<Optional<Entry<Integer, String>>> list4 =
    Arrays.<Optional<Entry<Integer, String>>>asList(optionalSimpleEntry);
```

Awooga! `Optional<SimpleEntry<xyz>>` is not an `Optional<Entry<xyz>>`.

You could use `Optional<? extends Entry<xyz>>`