# How can I re-bound a wildcard?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, bounded-wildcard

I'm implementing (single-pivot) Quicksort in Java.

I read there is a term of partitioning and I thought I can write a method with extensibility.

```java
    public static <E> void sort(
            final List<? extends E> list,
            final Comparator<? super E> comparator,
            final BiFunction<List<? extends E>, Comparator<? super E>, Integer> partitioner) {
        if (list.size() < 2) {
            return;
        }
        final int p = partitioner.apply(list, comparator);
        sort(list.subList(0, p), comparator, partitioner);
        sort(list.subList(p + 1, list.size()), comparator, partitioner);
    }
```

It seemed good to me. The original intention is giving a chance to select any partitioning logic with the `BiFunction` which takes the unsorted list and the comparator and returns the partitioning index.

And I tried to add another method for [Lomuto partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme).

```java
   static <E> void lomuto(final List<? extends E> list,
                          final Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        sort(list,
             comparator,
             (l, c) -> {
                 final E pivot = l.get(l.size() - 1);
                 int i = 0;
                 for (int j = 0; j < l.size() - 1; j++) {
                     if (c.compare(l.get(j), pivot) <= 0) {
                         swap(l, j, i++);
                     }
                 }
                 swap(l, l.size() - 1, i);
                 return i;
             });
    }
```

And the compiler complains at `c.compare(l.get(j), pivot)` part.

```
    Required type                                Provided
o1: capture of ? super capture of ? extends E    E
o2: capture of ? super capture of ? extends E    E
```

I found I can work around with

```
static <E> void lomuto(final List<E> list, final Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
```

How can I still do the PECS with `lomuto` method? `? extends E`?

Comment: Since you never use `E` directly, why would you want the `E` to be the most specific subtype? `List<E> list, Comparator<? super E> comparator` is the correct way to do it, for both methods.

Comment: as weird as it may seem those `? extends E` are different types. [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902219/nested-wildcards/58631449#58631449)

Comment: @Andreas Oh you're absolutely right. Can you please make it as an answer so that I can accept it? Even with PECS the list should be bounded with `<E>` cuz it's a producer and also a consumer.

Comment: Don't see how answer could be useful to anyone, as they'd be unlikely to be able to even find the question/answer, so I'd suggest just deleting the question. If you disagree, self-answer the question and accept your own answer. You might even get the [Self-Learner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) badge for that, if you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `<E>` of the `lomuto` method is not the `<E>` of the `sort` method. You wish the compiler to infer `lomuto`’s `E` as the type argument for `sort`’s type parameter, as the two methods have two congruent parameters, but that’s not how type inference works. All the compiler sees, are the three arguments for the `sort` method, a `List<? extends E>`, a `Comparator<? super E>`, and a poly expression. It will introduce special inference types which will then propagate to the poly expression.

When you use an explicit type argument to match the two `E`’s, the code compiles:

```
public static <E> void sort(
        final List<? extends E> list,
        final Comparator<? super E> comparator,
        final BiFunction<List<? extends E>, Comparator<? super E>, Integer> partitioner) {
    if (list.size() < 2) {
        return;
    }
    final int p = partitioner.apply(list, comparator);
    sort(list.subList(0, p), comparator, partitioner);
    sort(list.subList(p + 1, list.size()), comparator, partitioner);
}

static <E> void lomuto(final List<? extends E> list,
                      final Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    ContainingClass.<E>sort(list,
         comparator,
         (l,c) -> {
             final E pivot = l.get(l.size() - 1);
             int i = 0;
             for (int j = 0; j < l.size() - 1; j++) {
                 if (c.compare(l.get(j), pivot) <= 0) {
                     swap(l, j, i++);
                 }
             }
             swap(l, l.size() - 1, i);
             return i;
         });
}
```

Alternatively, you can provide explicit argument types for the lambda expression, so it isn’t a poly expression anymore:

```
// keep the sort method unchanged

static <E> void lomuto(final List<? extends E> list,
                      final Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    sort(list,
         comparator,
         (List<? extends E> l, Comparator<? super E> c) -> {
             final E pivot = l.get(l.size() - 1);
             int i = 0;
             for (int j = 0; j < l.size() - 1; j++) {
                 if (c.compare(l.get(j), pivot) <= 0) {
                     swap(l, j, i++);
                 }
             }
             swap(l, l.size() - 1, i);
             return i;
         });
}
```

Comment: what a beauty! I never thought that you could match those `E`s

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering for my own.

As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) commented, the `? extends E` of the `List` is not necessary and even wrong.

The `list` argument has both role of `consumer` and `producer`.

And the method should look look this.

```java
    public static <E> void sort(
            final List<E> list,
            final Comparator<? super E> comparator,
            final BiFunction<? super List<E>, ? super Comparator<? super E>, Integer> partitioner) {
        if (list.size() < 2) {
            return;
        }
        final int p = partitioner.apply(list, comparator);
        assert p >= 0;
        assert p < list.size();
        sort(list.subList(0, p), comparator, partitioner);
        sort(list.subList(p + 1, list.size()), comparator, partitioner);
    }
```

And the method for a specific partition scheme should look like this.

```java
    public static <E> void lomuto(final List<E> list,
                                  final Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        sort(list,
             comparator,
             (l, c) -> {
                 assert !l.isEmpty();
                 final int p = l.size() - 1;
                 int i = 0; // the index to be swapped with the pivot
                 for (int j = 0; j < l.size() - 1; j++) {
                     if (c.compare(l.get(j), l.get(p)) <= 0) {
                         swap(l, j, i++);
                     }
                 }
                 swap(l, p, i);
                 return i;
             });
    }
```

Comment: Using `List<? extends E>` might be unnecessary, but not wrong. Reordering is an operation that doesn’t count as “produce and consume”. Note how the `swap` calls do not produce any errors.