# Class implementing an interface is not accepted for generics wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I would like to have a map with the class type as a key in order to avoid casting when accessing the value.

**Update**
The following is actual code you can copy/paste in an IDEA and reproduce it.

```
    interface MyInterface {

    }

    class SomeConcreteClass implements MyInterface{

    }

    private Map<Class<?>, ? extends MyInterface> map = newMap();

    private Map<Class<?>, ? extends MyInterface> newMap() {
        Map<Class<?>, ? extends MyInterface> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(SomeConcreteClass.class, new SomeConcreteClass());
        return map;
    }

    private void accessMap() {
        SomeConcreteClass clazz = (SomeConcreteClass) map.get(SomeConcreteClass.class); <== I want to avoid cast here
    }
```

Problem: This does not compile. I get in this line:

```
map.put(SomeConcreteClass.class, new SomeConcreteClass());
```

the error:

> Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'SomeConcreteClass required '? extends
>   MyInterface`

What am I doing wrong here? `SomeConcreteClass` should be accepted as it implements the interface

Comment: Please post an actual non-working example; you've omitted a number of important details such as access modifiers and class structure.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- that's an actual non-working example, just tested it out and Idea tells that Required type: capture of ? extends MyInterface Provided: SomeConcreteClass

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-: That code in the post, if you copy/paste it in an IDEA you can reproduce the issue. Thank you Artsiom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified, a lot:

```
Map<String, ? extends CharSequence> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("", ""); // <-- will not compile

List<? extends CharSequence> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(""); // <-- will not compile
```

The principle behind this is called `PECS` (*very* famous). Why this is not allowed is a bit verbose to read, but mainly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58631449/1059372). Though not obvious, if that would be allowed - it might cause problems in other places, the answer I linked explains that.

You can achieve what you want with a so-called `typesafe heterogeneous container`:

```
static class TypeSafeValue {

    private MyInterface t;

    TypeSafeValue() {
    }

    public <T> TypeSafeValue setValue(MyInterface t) {
        this.t = t;
        return this;
    }

    public <T> T getValue(Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(t);
    }
}
```

And usage would be:

```
private Map<Class<?>, TypeSafeValue> newMap() {
    Map<Class<?>, TypeSafeValue> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(SomeConcreteClass.class, new TypeSafeValue().setValue(new SomeConcreteClass()));
    return map;
}

private void accessMap() {
    SomeConcreteClass clazz = map.get(SomeConcreteClass.class).getValue(SomeConcreteClass.class);
}
```

Comment: This is helpful indeed. By the way is there a solution to what I was trying to do there? I.e. avoid the cast?

Comment: @Jim I wanted to actually ask you, why do you think you need `? extends MyInterface` part? you do know you can declare it as `private Map<Class<?>, MyInterface> map = ...`, right? what is the actual benefit of introducing a bounded type in the `Map` declaration?