# List of Dogs List of animals... What is the solution?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I stumbled across the same problem as this guy in the related question:
[Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

Though I do understand why it is not possible to pass a `List<Dog>` to a method which accepts `List<Animal>`, as explained in the answers; I wonder what is ultimately the solution? Suppose I want the method to print the names of the objects in the list, like

```
public void printNames(List<Animal> list){
   for(Animal a : list){
      System.out.println(a.getName());
   }
}
```

Given that Animal implements getName(), this method would be safe to call with whatever list of animals or subtypes of that class. Since I can't do that, what is the best way to provide this functionality for whatever list of (sub)animals I might have?

I can say what does not work, which is the obvious way:

```
public void printNames(List<Dog> list){
   for(Dog d : list){
      System.out.println(d.getName());
   }
}
```

Because that throws nameClash: Both methods have same erasure

Comment: you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902219/nested-wildcards/58631449#58631449) for an extensive read. but the simple answer is `public void printNames(List<? extends Animal> list){ ... }`

Comment: But is `Dog` an `Animal` type in your code ?

Comment: Yes it is, I refer to the setup of the related answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you intend to do with the result.  Study ["PECS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) it will help.  In this case you can use a wildcard to solve it, but also generic methods and other techniques might be involved.

```
public void printNames(List<? extends Animal> list){
   for(Animal a : list){
      System.out.println(a.getName());
   }
}
```

You could also just use the `toString()` method, which might be better.

```
public void printAnything(List<?> list){
   for(Object a : list){
      System.out.println(a.toString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder what is ultimately the solution?

A wildcard:

```
public void printNames(List<? extends Animal> list){
```

Or, if you need to do something like put things into `list` that you took out of it, a type variable:

```
public <A extends Animal> void printNames(List<A> list){
```