# List<? super List<? super Integer>> and List<? extends List<? super Integer>> and how to use it correctly?

Tags: java, generics, jls, bounded-wildcard, unbounded-wildcard

Consider the following snippet:

```java
List<Double> doubleList = null;
List<Integer> integerList = null;
List<Number> numberList = null;

//expression:1
List<? super List<? super Integer>> superDoubleList = Arrays.asList(doubleList, integerList,numberList);

//expression:2
//here doubleList will cause compilation error
List<? extends List<? super Integer>> extendsDoubleList = Arrays.asList(integerList,numberList);//doubleList
```

- Here I am trying to understand how to interpret these two statements

  - **Expression:1**

    - Here we say that the List on the RHS must be such that all the elements of the list will satisfy the condition `? super List<? super Integer>`
    - but `doubleList` / `integerList` / `numberList` are not satisfying this condition anyhow - as we expect a type that is a supertype of `List<? super Integer>`.
    - **Still why are we not getting compilation error here?**
  - **Expression:2**

    - Here we expect that the elements on the RHS must be the `subtype of List<? super Integer>`
    - so `doubleList` intuitively can be seen as a candidate that can satisfy the condition.
    - **Why still I am getting compilation error if I include `doubleList` in the `Arrays.asList` expression?**.

**Not sure if I am interpreting the expressions in the right way - and what is wrong possibly that logically it does not seem to fit the explanation I gave above?**

Comment: Rather than thinking of super types and subtypes, you should think of `? super` and `? extends` as [consumers and producers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super), which makes everything easier to reason about.

Comment: I do not get a compiler error. Tested with JDK8, JDK11, JDK17. So I voted to close as unclear.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose You need to (I quote) "include `doubleList` in the `Arrays.asList` expression" to get the compiler error.

Comment: @Sweeper Arrgh. My fault. Mea culpa.

Comment: [may be this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902219/nested-wildcards/58631449#58631449)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two cases that compiles, compiles because the type inference algorithm tries its best to infer the type parameter for the `asList` call to make your code compile. It's not about the types of the three lists (they're only indirectly related). It's all about the type that `Arrays.asList` returns.

In the first case:

```
List<? super List<? super Integer>> superDoubleList = Arrays.asList(doubleList, integerList,numberList);
```

To make your code compile, `Arrays.asList`, just has to create a `List<List<?>>`. After all, the three lists are all "lists of *something*", so that is possible.

And `List<List<?>>` is a kind of `List<? super List<? super Integer>>`. This is because `List<?>` is a super type of `List<? super Integer>` - "a list of some `Integer` supertype" is a kind of "a list of some objects".

Another interpretation of this, is to think of `? super T` as "consumer of `T`" and `? extends T` as "producer of `T`". ([PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)) In this interpretation, `List<? super List<? super Integer>>` means "a list that can *consume* lists that can *consume* integers". "Consume" in the context of lists just means "add". Can a list containing `doubleList`, `integerList` and `numberList` do that? Sure, it doesn't matter what the contents of the list are, you can always add another `List<? super Integer>` to the list. It's just that the *type* of the list has to be `List<List<?>>`. Even this works:

```
List<? super List<? super Integer>> superDoubleList =
    Arrays.asList(new ArrayList<String>(), new ArrayList<LocalDate>());
```

Using the same interpretation, `List<? extends List<? super Integer>>` means "a list that can *produce* lists that *consume* integers". Can

```
Arrays.asList(integerList,numberList)
```

do that? Yes, both of those inner lists can consume integers, so the outer list can "produce lists that consume integers", or in other words, a *producer* of such lists.

What about this list of lists?

```
Arrays.asList(doubleList,integerList,numberList)
```

Is it a producer of lists that can consume integers? Well, no, because `doubleList` does not consume integers, but it can produce that.

You might be wondering what is the type that the Java compiler has inferred for `asList` in this case:

```
List<? extends List<? super Integer>> extendsDoubleList = Arrays.asList(integerList,numberList);
```

`asList` could create a `List<List<? super Integer>>`. However, the actual inferred type seems to be something else, that can't be expressed in Java's syntax.