# Assigning to multilevel wildcards

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Simple class:

```
class Pair<K,V> {

}
```

And a few assignments:

```
Collection<Pair<String,Long>> c1 = new ArrayList<Pair<String,Long>>();
Collection<Pair<String,Long>> c2 = c1; // ok
Collection<Pair<String,?>> c3 = c1; // this does not compile
Collection<? extends Pair<String,?>> c4 = c1; // ok
```

why does bullet number three not compile while the fourth one is perfectly legal?

Compiler error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection<Pair<String,Long>> to Collection<Pair<String,?>>
```

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: That does seem odd considering `Pair<String,?> c3 = new Pair<String,Long>();` is just fine!

Comment: And if you cast it to object and then back to the generic type it's also fine!

Comment: Time to call the JSL experts!

Comment: try `Collection<Pair<String, ? extends Long>> c3 = c1;`

Comment: @Zhuinden: If `?` does not compile, then `? extends ANYTHING` will not compile either.

Comment: That is indeed correct, in which case I'll stick around to see the final answer as I've lost the "why" behind it.

Comment: @JamieCockburn That's because nested wildcards act differently than top-level wildcards. I believe the term is that nested wildcards "don't capture"; that is, nested wildcards stand for *anything*, rather than one specific something.

Comment: @user3580294: The problem is not capturing or capture conversion here. Here, it is simply the invariance of generic types (see my answer). Capture conversion is again something different.

Comment: @gexicide Based on the answers I've read to similar questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3546745/3580294) I was under the impression that questions like these arise out of confusion about what the wildcard captures/doesn't capture. I didn't consider invariance to play that much of an explicit role, hence why invariance didn't appear in my answer. And what is capture conversion? Haven't heard that particular term before.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will try to explain the Java generics using two simple rules. These rules suffice to answer your question and are basically enough to remember for almost any case:

1. Two generic types `X<A>` and `X<B>` are never assignable unless `A = B`. I.e., generics are *invariant* by default.
2. Wildcards allow the assignment of `X<A>`:

   - to `X<?>`
   - to `X<? extends T>` iff `A` is assignable to `T` (apply rules recursively to `A` and `T`)
   - to `X<? super T>` iff `T` is assignable to `A` (apply rules recursively to `T` and `A`)

### Case `c3 = c1`

In your example, you try to assign `Collection<Pair<String,Long>>` to `Collection<Pair<String,?>>`. That is, in your case `A = Pair<String,Long>` and `B = Pair<String,?>`. Since these types are not equal, they are not assignable; they violate *Rule 1*.

The question is, why doesn't the wildcard help? The answer is simple:
Rule 2 is **NOT** transitive. I.e., `X<X<A>>` cannot be assinged to `X<X<?>>`, there has to be a wildcard in the outermost level; otherwise Rule 2 does not apply to the outermost level.

### Case `c4 = c1`

Here, you got a wildcard in the outer type. Because it is in the outer type, Rule 2 kicks in: `A = Pair<String,?>` is assignable to `B = ? extends Pair<String,Long>` (again, because of Rule 2). Therefore, this is legal.

### General approach

Here is how you can check any complex generic type: Simply check each generic level by level using the two rules. Start with the outermost level. Once a level violates a rules, you know the assignment is illegal; if all levels adhere to the rules, then the assignment is legal. Lets consider your types again:

```
X = Collection<Pair<String,Long>>
Y = Collection<Pair<String,?>>
Z = Collection<? extends Pair<String,?>>
```

Is X assignable to Y ?

```
// Outermost level:
A = Pair<String,Long>, B = Pair<String,?>
  => B is no wildcard and A != B (Rule 1), so this is illegal!
```

Is X assignable to Z ?

```
// Outermost level:
A = Pair<String,Long>, B = ? extends Pair<String,?>
  => We got a wildcard, so Rule 2 states this is legal if the inner level is legal
// Inner level: (we have to check both parameters)
A = String, B = String => Equal, Rule 1 applies, fine!
A = Long, B = ? => B is wildcard, Rule 2 applies, fine!
```

### Simple Rule to Remember

*Each level of generic nesting either needs to be completely identical (`A=B`) or `B` needs to contain a wildcard in this level.*

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let's simplify the code by removing extra type parameter:

```
Collection<List<Long>> c1 = new ArrayList<List<Long>>();
Collection<List<Long>> c2 = c1; // ok
Collection<List<?>> c3 = c1; // this does not compile
Collection<? extends List<?>> c4 = c1; // ok
```

We know that `List<? extends T>` essentially means "a `List` you can get `T` from", and `List<?>` is the same thing as `List<? extends Object>`.

So, types of the variables above can be explained as follows:

- c3: "a collection of `List`s that allow you to get `Object`s from them
- c4: "a collection that allows you to get `List`s that allow you to get `Object` from them

In particular, this explanation incurs the following:

```
// The following line compiles, 
// because `ArrayList<String>` is a `List` you can get `Object`s from
c3.add(new ArrayList<String>()); 

// The following line does not compile, 
// because type of c4 doesn't allow you to put anything into it
c4.add(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Now, it `c3 = c1` were allowed, you can see that `c3.add(new ArrayList<String>())` would break type safety of `c1`:

```
Collection<List<Long>> c1 = new ArrayList<List<Long>>();
Collection<List<?>> c3 = c1;

c3.add(Arrays.asList("foo")); 

for (List<Long> l: c1) {
    for (Long value: l) {
        // Oops, value is not a Long!
    }
}
```

Comment: c4 invalid? Why does it compile, then?

Comment: In the 2nd code block, you say //invalid, because type of c4 doesn't allow you to put anything into it... but c4 is ok for the compiler!

Comment: I'm talking about lines in this block, not about original declarations.

Comment: Collection<List<?>> c3 = c1; // this does not compile
// The following line compiles, 
c3.add(new ArrayList<String>()); 

You're either being confusing, or contradictory. I'm just pointing this out...

Answer (score 2):

The key thing to remember here is that *nested wildcards don't capture*.

What this means is that the "normal" behavior you expect from top-level wildcards (i.e. wildcards stand for one *specific* something) doesn't apply to nested wildcards. Instead, nested wildcards stand for *any* type.

For example, take this declaration:

```
List<?> l;
```

This means `l` is a `List` of one *specific* type. Easy.

But what about this?

```
Collection<List<?>> c;
```

This is *not* a `Collection` of `List`s of one specific type. This is a `Collection` of `List`s, *each of which* is one specific type.

For example, you were expecting something like this to happen:

```
Collection<List<?>> c = new ArrayList<List<Long>>(); // Not valid, but pretend it is
c.add(new ArrayList<Long>()); // Valid
c.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); // Invalid, because c is a Collection of Lists of Long
```

But consider this:

```
List<?> l = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add(l); // Should this compile?
```

The type of `l` exactly matches the type parameter for `c`, right? So shouldn't you be able to add `l` to `c`, even though `l` isn't a `List<Long>`?

Also consider this:

```
c.iterator().next(); // Assume there is an element to return
```

What type should this return? `iterator()` returns an `Iterator<E>`, and `next()` returns `E`, which means... `c.iterator().next()` returns a `List<?>`. Which is not the `List<Long>` you were expecting. Why is that?

Because *nested wildcards don't capture*. And that is the key distinction here. The wildcard in `List<?>` doesn't capture a single type "overall". It captures a single type *for each of the elements in the `Collection`*.

Thus, this is perfectly valid code:

```
Collection<List<?>> odd = new ArrayList<List<?>>();
odd.add(new ArrayList<String>());
odd.add(new ArrayList<Long>());
List<?> l = odd.iterator().next();
        // returns the ArrayList<String>, but because odd is parameterized with
        // List<?> we can technically end up with a list of anything
```

Keeping this in mind, let's look at your examples.

---

```
Collection<Pair<String,Long>> c1 = new ArrayList<Pair<String,Long>>();
Collection<Pair<String,Long>> c2 = c1;
```

That's intuitively OK. The types exactly match, so `c1` is assignable to `c2`.

---

```
Collection<Pair<String,Long>> c1 = new ArrayList<Pair<String,Long>>();
Collection<Pair<String,?>> c3 = c1;
```

Now, let's look back. A `Collection<Pair<String,?>>` isn't a `Collection` of `Pair`s of `String`s and a single unknown type. It's a `Collection` of `Pair`s, each of which is a pair of a `String` and some unknown type, which may or may not be the same type as another pair in the collection. So this is valid:

```
// Assume an appropriate object was assigned to c3
Pair<String, ?> p1 = new Pair<String, String>("Hello", "World");
Pair<String, ?> p2 = new Pair<String, List<String>>("Lorem", new ArrayList<>());
Pair<String, ?> p3 = new Pair<String, Map<String, Integer>>("Ispum", new HashMap<>());
c3.add(p1);
c3.add(p2);
c3.add(p3);
```

And because this is valid for `c3`, but shouldn't be valid for `c1`, assigning `c1` to `c3` isn't allowed, because it would allow you to put stuff into an `ArrayList<Pair<String, Long>>` that isn't a `Pair<String, Long>`.

---

```
Collection<Pair<String,Long>> c1 = new ArrayList<Pair<String,Long>>();
Collection<? extends Pair<String,?>> c4 = c1;
```

Now, this is a bit more tricky. The top-level captures one *specific* type that extends `Pair<String, ?>`. Because wildcards are supertypes of specific types (e.g. `List<?>` is a supertype of `List<Integer>`), `Pair<String, Long>` can be captured by `? extends Pair<String, ?>`, because the former extends the latter. Thus, because `Pair<String, Long>` is assignment-compatible with `? extends Pair<String, ?>`, the assignment is valid.

---

As you can tell from the variety of answers here, there are multiple ways of explaining the behavior of nested wildcards. I was going for a bit more of an intuitive explanation, which I hope I achieved.

Answer (score 1):

One of the advantages of Java generics is stronger type checks at compile time. So anything declared in generics should exactly match. To make it a simple answer I would use some examples.

To initialize a list of numbers you could do like.

```
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

This technically means the List "numbers" can store any object that is either a number or sub-class of number. But we cannot initilaize this list with sub types. Anything given in generic tags `<>` should literally match the assignment. (Java 7 provides a type inference though)

```
List<Number> intNumbers = new ArrayList<Interger>(); // Compile Error
List<Number> doubleNumbers = new ArrayList<Double>(); // Compile Error
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); // Compile Error
```

Even though Integer and Double are subclasses of Number the generics prevents from these initialization. The generic argument specified inside `<>` should exactly match.

Now if assignment is tightly bound how can the numbers list store sub-class objects? The answer is the `add(), addlAll().. etc` methods accepts `E` or anything that extends `E`, where `E` is the generic type we gave. So in case of the list "numbers" E is `Number` so the following statements are perfectly valid.

```
List<Integer> intNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
numbers.add(new Integer(1));
numbers.add(new Double(1.0));
numbers.addAll(intNumbers);
```

Again one exception to this is the wildcards. The wildcard is used to accept any arguments. So the following statments are valid.

```
List<?> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
Map<?, ?> unKnownMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

// OR

List<Integer> intNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<?> numbers = intNumbers;
```

Similarly

```
Pair<String,?> p = new Pair<String, Long>(); // Is valid.
```

But now we cannot add anything to this list as the element should extend `?` and that is an unknown type and the only allowable element is `null`, which is a member of every type. Java does not infer this from the assignment. So the following result in error

```
List<?> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>(); // Works fine.
numbers.add(new Integer(1)); // Compile Error
numbers.add(new Double(1.0)); // Compile Error
```

Also the wildcard inference happens only on one level. Any nesting should again match exactly like usual generics. So

```
List<List<?>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); // Compile error because nested List<String> doesn not exactly match List<?>
List<List<?>> list = new ArrayList<List<?>>(); // OK - Valid 
List<List<Integer>> intList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
List<List<?>> numbers = intList; // Compile error because nested List<Integer> doesn not exactly match List<?>
```

So this is your case

```
Collection<Pair<String,Long>> c1 = new ArrayList<Pair<String,Long>>();
Collection<Pair<String,Long>> c2 = c1; // ok
Collection<Pair<String,?>> c3 = c1; // Compile error because nested Pair<String,?> doesn not exactly match Pair<String,Long>
```

So you could do something like

```
Collection<Pair<String,?>> c3 = new ArrayList<Pair<String,?>>(c2);
//OR
Collection<Pair<String,?>> c3 = new ArrayList<Pair<String,?>>();
c3.addAll(c2);
```

Case 4: When you say `List<? extends List<?>>` its again first level. That means it checks whether the element under question extends `List<?>`.

```
List<? extends List<?>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); // Works similar to List<?> l = new ArrayList<String>();
List<? extends List<List<?>>> numbers = new ArrayList<List<List<String>>>(); // Compile error - Nested level similar to List<List<String>> lst = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

So `Collection<Pair<String,?>> c3 = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Long>>();` is similar to `Pair<String,?> p = new Pair<String, Long>();`

Comment: But why does assigning Pair<String, Long> to Pair<String, ?> not cause a problem, then?