# How to apply complex generic method to class with wildcard generic type?

Tags: java, generics

There are something like:

```java
<T> Identifier<Set<T>> myMethod(Iterable<? extends Element<Identifier<T>>> input) {…}
```

```java
class MyClass implements Element<Identifier<?>> {…}
```

```java
Iterable<MyClass> a = …;
```

How could I pass `a` to `myMethod` to get `Identifier<Set<?>>`?

Comment: What happens when you call `myMethod(a)`?

Comment: If you can, you should avoid using a wildcard in an implements clause.

Comment: @AlexR `error: method myMethod in class … cannot be applied to given types;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `blabla.myMethod((Iterable) a)`;

More specifically:

`Identifier<Set<?>> setIdentifier = blabla.myMethod((Iterable) a);`

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over `myMethod`, make its signature more flexible:

```
<T> Identifier<Set<T>> myMethod(Iterable<? extends Element<Identifier<? extends T>>> input)
```

And while that's enough to solve your issue, this would be the most flexible:

```
<T> Identifier<Set<T>> myMethod(Iterable<? extends Element<? extends Identifier<? extends T>>> input)
```

See also:

- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)
- [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu)